# I want change cell.textContent to string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a javascript function that use `cell.textContent` for calling a php file

```
var title = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[Row_Index].cells[0].textContent;

//Actions for delete from DB
            $.ajax({
            url: 'h.php',
            data: {group_title: title},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    //Actions for delete from table
                    element.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                }
                else {
                    alert("حذف گروه امکان پذیر نمی باشد");
                }
            }
        });
```

I am going to use it in sql statement in php file but it does not work right

Comment: Have you logged what `title` receives for a value? What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: try: `data: {group_title: S},` to `data:title;`

Comment: @ScottMarcus when I send string value php file return true value but when send 'title' return wrong

Comment: @zer00ne I wrote it wrong in question  that I correct it

Comment: when i try by a sting var like str="test" work right but with "title" var work wrong

Comment: @Hamedzamanyad Again, have you logged what `title` is evaluating out to?

Comment: When I changed ...cell[0].textContent;   to ...cell[0].inner;  Text the problem solved